# Nothing dropping down from drop down menu in navigation bar HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

I've looked through other questions but none seem to explain the problem I'm having. I want to create a drop down menu to an already existing navigation bar, and I think it's a problem with the way I've named the classes.

Here is my HTML code for the nav bar

```
<ul class="customMenu">
    <li class="customList"><a class="menuActif" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="customList extendMenuClass"><a class="extendMenu" href="#">Cities</a></li>
    <div class="extendedDiv">
        <a href="...">Paris</a>
        <a href="...">Lyon</a>
        <a href="...">Toulouse</a>
    </div>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">Phrases</a></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">Bank Accounts</a></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">Important Notes</a></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">CAF</a></li>
    <li class="customList" style="float:right"><a class="menuActif" onClick="verifDecon()">Déconnexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS I have tried to implement:

```
.customMenu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #00264d;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.customList {
  float: left;
}

.customList a, .extendMenu{
  font-family: Sans Serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 17px;
  display: block; 
  color: white;
}

.customList a:hover, .extendMenuClass:hover .extendMenu{
  background-color: #00264d;
  color: red;
}

.menuActif{
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.menuActif:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: #00264d;
}

.customList.extendMenuClass{
  display: inline-block;
}

.extendedDiv{
  display: none;
  background-color: #00264d;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.extendedDiv a{
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.extendedDiv a:hover{
  color: red;
}

.extendMenuClass:hover .extendedDiv{
  display: block;
}
```

I works otherwise, the menu just doesn't drop down. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector to show the menu on hover is `.extendMenuClass:hover .extendedDiv`, but `.extendedDiv` is not a child of `.extendMenuClass`. Updated that so that it is a child and that selector will work.

Then you need to remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.customMenu` since `.extendedDiv` will bleed below/outside of `.customMenu` and will be hidden if overflow is hidden.

```css
.customMenu {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: #00264d;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
.customList {
  float: left;
}

.customList a, .extendMenu{
  font-family: Sans Serif;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px 17px;
  display: block; 
  color: white;
}

.customList a:hover, .extendMenuClass:hover .extendMenu{
  background-color: #00264d;
  color: red;
}

.menuActif{
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}

.menuActif:hover{
  background-color: white;
  color: #00264d;
}

.customList.extendMenuClass{
  display: inline-block;
}

.extendedDiv{
  display: none;
  background-color: #00264d;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.extendedDiv a{
  display: block;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

.extendedDiv a:hover{
  color: red;
}

.extendMenuClass:hover .extendedDiv{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="customMenu">
    <li class="customList"><a class="menuActif" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="customList extendMenuClass"><a class="extendMenu" href="#">Cities</a>
    <div class="extendedDiv">
        <a href="...">Paris</a>
        <a href="...">Lyon</a>
        <a href="...">Toulouse</a>
    </div></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">Phrases</a></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">Bank Accounts</a></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">Important Notes</a></li>
    <li class="customList"><a href="#">CAF</a></li>
    <li class="customList" style="float:right"><a class="menuActif" onClick="verifDecon()">Déconnexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but how do I go about making .extendedDiv a child of .extendMenuClass ?

Comment: @AndrewY compare my code to yours. You move `.extendedDiv` into `.extendMenuClass`

Comment: Aha I see! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Common syntax for navigation is nesting unordered lists inside other unordered lists.

so you'd set it up like:

```
<ul class="main-nav">
    <li>1</li>
    <li class="dropdown">2
        <ul class="dropdown-list">
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
            <li>2.3</li>
    </li>
    <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

It's a lot easier to keep parent and child elements in order.

I just set it up a little easier for you to follow and continually add items:

## HTML:

```
<ul class="customMenu">
    <li style="background:red;"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="extend"><a href="#">Cities</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="#">Paris</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Lyon</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Toulouse</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Phrases</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bank Accounts</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Important Notes</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CAF</a></li>
    <li style="background: red; float: right;"><a href="#">Déconnexion</a></li>
</ul>
```

## CSS:

```
ul.customMenu {
  width: 100%;
  background: #00264d;
}
ul.customMenu li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul.customMenu li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 23px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 16px 17px;
}
ul.customMenu li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
ul.customMenu li ul.dropdown {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: -5px;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
ul.customMenu li ul.dropdown li a {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 16px 20px;
}
ul.customMenu li ul.dropdown li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: #cc0000 !important;
}

li.extend {
  position: relative;
}
li.extend:hover ul.dropdown {
  display: block !important;
}
```